# Accessing domain redirects to subdomain and displays ip instead of hostname in browser

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, subdomain

I am trying to set up a domain and some subdomains in a vps. This seems to work correctly when I access through Firefox but on my phone or on Chrome I am redirected to the subdomain. This is the access log for a Chrome request to themendez.de:

```
test.themendez.de:80 5.28.115.219 - - [27/Jul/2013:15:38:35 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 504 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
test.themendez.de:80 5.28.115.219 - - [27/Jul/2013:15:38:37 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
test.themendez.de:80 5.28.115.219 - - [27/Jul/2013:15:38:37 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
```

this is the access log for a request to themendez.de from Firefox:

```
themendez.de:80 5.28.115.219 - - [27/Jul/2013:15:39:17 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
```

and this from my phone:

```
test.themendez.de:80 5.28.115.219 - - [27/Jul/2013:15:41:56 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 210 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; en-de; HTC_One_X Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
```

output of apachectl -S

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server test.themendez.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.themendez.de:1)
         port 80 namevhost test.themendez.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.themendez.de:1)
         port 80 namevhost themendez.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/themendez.de:1)
Syntax OK
```

I have absolutely not idea what is going on... if you need any more info I can provide it.

Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: The answer isn't in the information you posted.  The subdomain redirect could be anywhere in your configuration.  The error log, as opposed to the access log, might contain useful information.  If not, you'll probably have to crank up LogLevel and/or turn on RewriteLog, and start digging through the log files.

Comment: error.log doesn't change at all and adding rewriteLog and changing LogLevel also don't seem to be very helpful here... I'll post vhosts configuration maybe I'm messing up somewhere there

Comment: Good choice on deciding to post your actual domain here.  It helps tremendously in diagnosing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Firefox example looks to have hit a different site to the other two.  The log file is `themendez.de` instead of `test.themendez.de`.  This isn't the problem but it's worth noting the inconsistency in your investigations.

When I tried requests to those two sites myself, the former gave me an IIS redirect to an IP address, the latter gives a 200 response with a default Apache "It works" page.

I suspect, however, that the true problem is with your DNS settings.  Both of those domains have two A records:

```
themendez.de.           1692    IN      A       98.124.198.1
themendez.de.           1692    IN      A       151.236.15.23
```

The 151.236.15.23 server is running Apache, the 98.124.198.1 server is running IIS.  It is pretty much random which of the two IP addresses will be chosen when two A records are returned so either domain can hit either server.

The 98.124.198.1 IP address appears to be a parked domain system and redirects to `http://searchezy.com/`.

You also have not changed the default records for www.themendez.de so this domain is being parked by your DNS provider as well.

Comment: I think you've hit the jackpot, although I still can't quite figure out where 98.124.198.1 is coming from